# Aurelia parent view model method is not binding

Tags: aurelia

Hi I am having some binding issues with latest aurelia release, it is working with "1.0.0-beta.1.0.5".

After one week struggling i have identified this is with aurelia new version. Can any one help how i can fix the issue in the below plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/AzFS8rrZdXlzfLHOVqw9?p=preview

below is the structure :

```
app.html

<gird>
  <grid-col>
    <button click.trigger="test()">Click</button>
  </grid-col>
</grid>
app.js 
export class App {
  test() {
    alert('some test')
  }
 }
```

I am not able access test() method.

Could any please help what the mistake i did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot tell you why you are having this problem. However, I see that you trying to do something very simple, that usually do not cause any kind of stress or difficulty.

In my opinion, your grid component contains too much code. It should not be that big. It seems like simple component, and I think you should rewrite that.

Be sure you are making good use of `<content></content>` inside your components. (Be aware that the `<content></content>` tag will change to `<slot></slot>` in the next few releases.

Here is an example of a simple component, calling a function of its parent.

http://plnkr.co/edit/56ws7IS3RVQjQ99gJj1T?p=preview

Try to recreate your component, using the `let` and `var` correctly this time (I think you misused them in some parts of your code). Perhaps the error is being caused by some other problem in your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @fabio-luz
 I will clean the code. But what is mistake i am doing here i want know. If i know the mistake i will not repeat the same mistake another time

Comment: I have find out the issue. In latest aurelia release instruction.inheritBindingContext = false.  if we change this to true via @processContent(), parent bindings are working perfectly